# PARSE signUp with NSErrorPointer in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I want to use the `signUp(error: NSErrorPointer)` function of PARSE in swift.
I tried this:

```
var newUser = PFUser()
...
var errorN:NSErrorPointer
newUser.signUp(error: errorN)
```

But it does not work, it says extra argument in call.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
var errorN: NSError?
newUser.signUp(&errorN)
```

This should allow you to handle the NSError** conversion from the original Objective-C method. See here for more on NSErrorPointer: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html

Comment: What Xcode are you using? I tried with Xcode 6.3 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to user NSErrorPointer(). Here is revised code that works.

```
    var newUser = PFUser()
    ...
    var errorN = NSErrorPointer()
    newUser.signUp(error: errorN)
```